# How to use readonly when @Transactional is on class level

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

I am using `@Transactional` on my `service` class which call `DAO` methods
and I was wondering how can I use read only on specific service method.
Do I have to define extra `@Transactional` with `readonly=true` on this service method, or there's another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Spring API [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

*The most derived location takes precedence when evaluating the transactional settings for a method. In the case of the following example, the DefaultFooService class is annotated at the class level with the settings for a read-only transaction, but the @Transactional annotation on the updateFoo(Foo) method in the same class takes precedence over the transactional settings defined at the class level.*

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

  public Foo getFoo(String fooName) {
    // do something
  }

  // these settings have precedence for this method
  @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void updateFoo(Foo foo) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

*The @Transactional annotation is metadata that specifies that an interface, class, or method must have transactional semantics; for example, “start a brand new read-only transaction when this method is invoked, suspending any existing transaction”. The default @Transactional settings are as follows:*

Propagation setting is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED.

Isolation level is ISOLATION_DEFAULT.

Transaction is read/write.

Transaction timeout defaults to the default timeout of the underlying transaction system, or to none if timeouts are not supported.

Any RuntimeException triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not.

Comment: when using @Transactional only without the readonly attribute, does that means that readonly=false by default or what?

Comment: `readonly` [defaults to false](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#readOnly%28%29)

Comment: I have updated the answer with the complete list of default values.