# Spring @Transactional on class vs on method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm using `Spring Boot` and `Spring Data JPA`.

Having following class:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class Foo{

    public void bar(){}

}
```

will `bar()` and any other member method be also transactional?

**I also have second question.** On many tutorials people tend to do something like this:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
public class Foo{

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void bar(){}

}
```

Why? Is using `readOnly` `true` and `false` a it matter of security?

Comment: Yes. That's quite clearly explained in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative-annotations

Comment: There are 2 questions here: First question is about which methods are transactional when the annotation is at the class level. The second question is about overriding the annotation at the method level. I still can't see an answer to the first question. Thoughts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**The annotation at the method level completely overrides the annotation at the type-level.**

The `@Transactional` annotation on the class level will be applied to every method in the class.

However, when a method is annotated with `@Transactional`, this will take precedence over the transactional settings defined at the class level.

Comment: @ex3v and your question is already answered by this answer. Re-read it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unclear. I understand your answer about class level vs method level. I just don't understand why people use `readOnly = true` on class level and `readOnly = false` on method level.

Comment: @ex3v because they want all the methods of the class to be read-only by default, except the ones which are annotated with readOnly=false.

Comment: @ex3v any help from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604931/how-to-use-readonly-when-transactional-is-on-class-level)