# Spring @Transactional read-only

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file

With this dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I've created this service declared as readOnly:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class TimeLapseService {

    @Autowired
    TimeLapseRepository timeLapseRepository;

    public Set<TimeLapse> findAllByCompanyId(long companyId) {
        return timeLapseRepository.findAllByCompanyId(companyId);
    }

    public Iterable<TimeLapse> findAll (User user) {

        if (user.isAdmin()) {
            return timeLapseRepository.findAll();
        } else {
            return timeLapseRepository.findAllByCompanyId(user.getCompany().getId());
        }   

    }

    public void createTimeLapse (TimeLapse timeLapse) {
        timeLapseRepository.save (timeLapse);
    }

}
```

and

```
public interface TimeLapseRepository extends CrudRepository<TimeLapse, Long> {
....
}
```

As far as I know, since the service is declared as readonly, creating a new service shouldn't persist anything to the DB, but it creates a row in the TABLE

```
timeLapseService.createTimeLapse(timeLapse24h);
```

JPA properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: How did you check that you have a new record, do you see it in a different transaction (from your DB client for example)? Add also the jpa configurations you have.

Comment: May be method level u override class level transaction.

Comment: why don't you  try to override the readonly for your save method like this

Comment: @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void createTimeLapse (TimeLapse timeLapse) {
        timeLapseRepository.save (timeLapse);
    }

Comment: Clearly explained over here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604931/how-to-use-readonly-when-transactional-is-on-class-level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> BeanS call a transactional=read-only Bean1, which does a lookup and
>   calls transactional=read-write Bean2 which saves a new object.

```
> Bean1 starts a read-only tx. 31 09:39:44.199 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG
> o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name
> [nz.co.vodafone.wcim.business.Bean1.startSomething]:
> PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''

> 
> Bean 2 pariticipates in it. 31 09:39:44.230 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG
> o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Participating in existing
> transaction
>
```

> Nothing is committed to the database.
>
> Now change Bean2 @Transactional annotation to add
>   propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW

```
> Bean1 starts a read-only tx. 31 09:31:36.418 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG
> o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name
> [nz.co.vodafone.wcim.business.Bean1.startSomething]:
> PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
> 
> Bean2 starts a new read-write tx 31 09:31:36.449 [pool-1-thread-1]
> DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Suspending current
> transaction, creating new transaction with name
```

Unless you make as below it would be persisted

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createTimeLapse (TimeLapse timeLapse)
   { 
    timeLapseRepository.save (timeLapse); 
   }
```